# Phonegap connection plugin not woking in turkish language

Tags: android, cordova, turkish

I am using connection plugin in my phone gap app, to check connection type. It works OK in all tested languages (eng, her, fr, es and some other common), but fails to return connection type, when language is set to turkish in my android device.

Any thoughts what causes this problem (and how to fix)?

Details:

```
var isWifi = navigator.connection.type === Connection.WIFI;
```

is expected to be true, but in turkish `connection.type` is `unknown`

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in Connection plugin implementation:

```
type.toLowerCase().equals(WIFI)
```

where `type` is `ConnectionType` obtained from Android API and `WIFI` is a const. In turkish `type.toLowerCase()` returns 'wıfı' that has 'i' letter not matching the ones from const.

Solution:

change check condition to:

```
type.equalsIgnoreCase(WIFI)
```